# Should I not use (nonatomic, weak) for UIViewController property?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, automatic-ref-counting

I have a property on one of my objects like so:

```
@property(nonatomic, weak) UIViewController *myParentViewController;
```

However, in the [ARC release notes](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html) it says:

> Note: In addition, in OS X v10.7, you cannot create weak references to
>   instances of NSFontManager, NSFontPanel, NSImage, NSTableCellView,
>   NSViewController, NSWindow, and NSWindowController. In addition, in OS
>   X v10.7 no classes in the AV Foundation framework support weak
>   references.

So I changed the property to `assign` instead, but now when I type `myParentViewController`, the autocomplete shows that it is `unsafe_unretained`, which scares me a little bit.

What exactly is going on here? What should I be careful of with unsafe_unretained? Have I interpreted the documentation correctly?

Comment: The `UIViewController` is not on the list; why do you think it may be a problem in your case?

Comment: Well UIViewController is the NSViewController equivalent for iOS. The document was written for Mac, but I supposed it applies to iOS as well.

Comment: why not make it `strong` then?

Comment: Because that will lead to a retain cycle..

Comment: Most documentation of this nature is the same between iOS and OS X.  You can access the iOS version by replacing `library/mac` in the URL with `library/ios`.  [Like so.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Comment: You'll note that even in the iOS documentation, `UIViewController` is not listed.

Comment: [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html) is the iOS link, `UIViewController` is not listed there either.

Answer (score 2):

`UIViewController` is not in that list, which refers only to OS X anyway.  You are misinterpreting the documentation.  What holds true for OS X does not necessarily have a direct equivalence in iOS.